# Creating art on yom tov

Tags: yom-tov, art

If someone created a work of art (e.g., drawing, painting or sculpture) by mistake on Yom Tov, what can be done with it? Does it have to be destroyed or can it be kept?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501). Since this site doesn't provide halachic answers to personal questions, I took the liberty to edit your question to depersonalize it. Hope that helps and hope to see you around!

Comment: Could you clarify what the mistake is? Is the mistake not knowing it was yom tov? Or not knowing that drawing/painting was forbidden?

Answer (score 1):

If work that it forbidden by torah law, such as writing or painting, was done by mistake on Shabbos or Yom Tov, no one derive pleasure from it on that day. After Shabbos or Yom Tov, all may enjoy it.

If it was done with the knowledge that it was forbidden, then the one who did it and his family may not derive pleasure from it forever. Others may enjoy it after Shabbos or Yom Tov. There may be more of a reason to be lenient by Yom Tov.

(Shulchan Aruch 318/1 and Biur Halacha 527/23)

Comment: Is hanging it on the wall considered deriving pleasure?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Good point.  The מאור השבת חלק א' סי' י"ח הלכה נ"ב דף תל"א quotes  Dayan Fisher  that it would be a forbidden pleasure, if something was made to enjoy it's sight. That is also the opinion on Rav Elyashiv, quoted at the end  ארחות שבת פרק כ"ה.  However, the מאור השבת writes that Rav Chaim Kanievsky considered permitting it. There are two similar area's that this questions comes up, by Avoda Zorah, and using a cadaver to learn medicine.

Comment: Ok well that seems to be the important stuff for this post.

Comment: @DoubleAA -  Not really, because the question was if it was done by mistake.

Comment: Ok, so can you look at it on Shabbat or does it need to be disposed of ASAP? And what about for the Gra who Paskins like R Meir?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Is the Gr"a talking about D'Oraisa or only D"Rabbonon?